# C++ : Why isn't my (permuted index) code printing out correctly?

Tags: c++, rotation, permutation

I'm walking myself though Accelerated C++'s problems and this is the first one i'm having any sort of trouble with.

The problem is to code a program that is able to generate a [permuted index](http://everything2.com/title/permuted+index) from a set of lines.

The code below has two functions: permutedIndex5_1 which is the "main()" function of sorts, and  permuteLine5_1 which takes a given line (and a reference to an vector of already permuted lines) and permutes the given line rotationally, adding each rotation to the vector.

The problem i'm having is that the permuted lines are printing out incorrectly on stdout. I've included several 3 debug statements in permuteLine5_1 to test the first and last strings to be printed, and the results of those print statements show what *should* be printed out, however what is being printed out is completely different.

My gut feeling is that it may have to do with me erasing the iterator in that function, but i'm not sure how to rectify it. In any case, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The contents of the text file read are :

> The quick brown fox
>   The slow brown fox
>   The quick blue dog

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


using std::fstream;
using std::ios;
using std::istringstream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void permuteLine5_1(vector< vector<string> >& lines, vector<string> curLine)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < curLine.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string>::iterator curBeginStrItr = curLine.begin();
        string curBeginStr = *curBeginStrItr;

        curLine.erase(curBeginStrItr);
        curLine.push_back(curBeginStr);

        cout << "The first string in the current line is : "  + *(curLine.begin()) << endl;
        cout << "The first string in the current line is VIA INDEXING IS : "  + curLine[0] << endl;
        cout << "The last string in the current line is : "  + *(curLine.rbegin()) << endl;

        for(int j = 0; j < curLine.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << curLine[j];
        }
        cout << endl;

        lines.push_back(curLine);
    }


}

void permutedIndex5_1()
{
    vector< vector<string> > lines;

    fstream fileLines;
    fileLines.open("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\lines.txt", ios::in);

    string curLine, curWord;
    vector<string> curLineVec;

    while(getline(fileLines, curLine))
    {
        cout << curLine << endl;

        curLineVec.push_back("|");

        istringstream strS(curLine);

        while(getline(strS, curWord, ' '))
        {
            curLineVec.push_back(curWord);
            cout << curWord << endl;  
        }

        lines.push_back(curLineVec);
        curLineVec.clear();
    }

    vector< vector<string> > permuted;

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        permuteLine5_1(permuted, lines[i]);
    }

    sort(permuted.begin(), permuted.end());

    /*Code below prints out permutations. Commented out because
      permuting function does not work properly

    for(int i = 0; i < permuted.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> curVec = permuted[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < curVec.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << curVec[j] << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
    }*/


}
```

Comment: What should it print, and what does it print instead?

Comment: It just doesn't rotate the line correctly. The "|" string always displays first on stdout despite my debug statements telling me otherwise. Also, some of the letters of the strings are being deleted, which I don't understand since I don't touch characters individually at all. That's why I think it has something to do with the string I push back, since it is a reference to the string that the iterator I deleted pointed to... i'm not even sure why the code works as is, since the string should be invalidated from my understanding.

Comment: I took only permuteLine5_1 for a test drive, and it works just fine for me (I'm using Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: Update - Your whole program works fine for me on VS 2010.

Comment: Ok, testing it in Visual Studio Express 2008, it appears that that part of my code works correctly... strange. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work correctly in NetBeans?

Comment: Eldad Mor, if you would be so kind as to re-submit your comment as an answer, i'd be glad to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your iterator erasing is fine, because you make a real copy of the string first, and your invalidated iterator is not subsequently used.

I'd simplify the permutation a bit to...

```
for(int i = 0; i < curLine.size(); i++)
{
    string curBeginStr = curLine[0];

    curLine.erase(curLine.begin());
    curLine.push_back(curBeginStr);
```

<strike>But, I think the real problem is in the sort, and I'm a bit surprised it compiles:</strike>

```
sort(permuted.begin(), permuted.end());
```

You're trying to sort a vector of vectors of string - which means that the sort algorithm needs to somehow compare two vectors of strings to determine order. I think it can't do that, and that you'll need to provide a custom sorting predicate to perform the exact comparison you want.

Thanks to Chris for the correction.

Comment: vector::operator<() compares vectors lexicographically: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operators/